# Pull only text left of "-"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using T-SQL. 
I have these two strings.

```
AX20-xxxxxxxx
T11-xxxxxxxxx
```

For the first one I want to be able to pull `AX`

For the second I would like only `T`.

Comment: please tag your dbms.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a site where you can ask questions and get answers about problems you're having with software you've written, but it is not a "do my homework for me" or "do my job for me" site. When you ask a question you should include the code you've written and the specific errors you're getting or the results your program produces and an explanation of the results you expected. Without that there's really not much we can do to help you. Please edit your question to show what you've done and tell us what problems the code has. Again, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Guaranteed this is homework.

Comment: google your dbms name and "regexp", with 30 minutes you'd solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you need to get the substring from the beginning to the occurrence of first number, use `PATINDEX` to get the index of the first number and `SUBSTRING` thereafter.

```
select substring(colname, 1, patindex('%[0-9]%',colname)-1)
from tablename
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a peek at PatIndex()

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'AX20-xxxxxxxx'
Select Left(@S,PatIndex('%[0-9]%',@S)-1)
```

Returns

```
AX
```

Comment: This is a cleaner solution

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Meh..  Tomato, Potato.   However, I'm a Python guy, but I can't imagine all of that would be required.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server you can use [PATINDEX()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) to get first digit occurrence and then use [LEFT()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) function to get left substring

```
WITH T AS 
(
  SELECT 'AX20-xxxxxxxx' as Str
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'T11-xxxxxxxxx' as Str
)
SELECT LEFT(Str,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Str)-1) FROM T
```